# How to put INTENT_CONFIDENCE asserter as a global variable in Botium

Tags: node.js, testing, chatbot

My question is about how to set the INTENT_CONFIDENCE as a global asserter instead of put it all over the convos.

I tried it two ways in botium.json configuration file, but both are not working:

within the "ASSERTERS" capability, I tried:

```
  "INTENT_CONFIDENCE": 100 -- I have done the same but with "100"/ "100 %"
```

and

```
  "ref": "INTENT_CONFIDENCE", 
  "val": "100"
```

the error looks like

```
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1133
      else throw err
           ^

Error: Failed to fetch package botium-asserter-undefined - { Error: Cannot find module 'botium-asserter-undefined'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the JSON configuration to use:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      ...
      "ASSERTERS": [
        {
          "ref": "INTENT_CONFIDENCE",
          "src": "IntentConfidenceAsserter",
          "global": true,
          "args": {
            "expectedMinimum": 80
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```